# Change array index for each value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So far my `var_dump()` of a $records array looks like:

```
array (size=1)
  25 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[51]
          public 'id' => 25
          public 'name' => info...
          public 'surname' => info...
```

I wan't to change that 0 index name to object id (25) name but it just adds one more dimension above my current one. This is how I do it:

```
foreach ($records as $value) {
    $records = array($value->id=>$records);
}
```

I want my array to look like this though:

```
array (size=1)
  25 => 
    object(stdClass)[51]
     public 'id' => 25
     public 'name' => info...
     public 'surname' => info...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating keys so they equal the ID:

```
$tmp= array();
foreach ($records as $value) {
    $tmp[$value->id] = $value;
}
$records = $tmp;
```

Comment: hmm maybe I wasn't clear enough or I don't understand. I want to rename the original index of my array $records[0] to $records[$value->id] and do it in my loop so in case I have more indexes all of them get renamed after their id

Comment: I've updated my code. Basically you build a new array and just set the key using the method I've shown.

Comment: I see it works, however I now have a new array variable called $results... Any chance I can keep the same old name? A lot of code is depending on it

Comment: Yeah, you want to overwrite the old name with the name new `$origName = $newName`. You must use a temporary name because you cannot loop through and modify the original array at the same time.

Comment: I see, can I rename it in the loop?

Comment: You have to do the loop first then rename it afterwards. I'll update my code

Comment: You don't want to overwrite the array until after the loop because otherwise you are modifying the data as you are looping through it. This question is pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works